# Allocating an array of two dimensions of struct in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-struct

I have a problem, I want to allocate a block of memory of size m and n (so a 2D matrix) where each element of the matrix is a struct of 2 variables ( a point with 2 double coordinates x and y). The language I want to write this in is MATLAB
I have tried something like this:

```
left = zeros(height, width);
for i = 1 : width
  for j = 1 : height
     var.x = someValue;
     var.y = someOtherValue;
     left(i,j) = var;
```

The piece of code from above doesn't work.. How can I fix the problem?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

```
left(height,width) = struct();
for i = 1 : width
  for j = 1 : height
    left(j,i).x = someValue;
    left(j,i).y = someOtherValue;
  end
end
```

should do what you want

Comment: Thaks for the response, however it doesn't work... the error is: Subscripted assignment between dissimilar structures.Try implementing it for 1 value to see

Comment: I do not have matlab here, it seems to work in Octave. Did you `clear left` before trying?

Comment: Thank you for the response! I was not clearing left before the doing the operations. I put a clear left before the instructions and everything works ok :).